# Android: Battery usage while switching wifi ON/OFF

Tags: android

Ive been developing an app that switches wifi on and off depending upon certain triggers. I just wanted to know that if battery consumption will be higher with cycling wifi on and off every 10 mins. And will the same apply for data if that too is cycled.

Thanks,
Sahil

Comment: You could always test/benchmark it.

Comment: I am new at programming how can i do that.

Comment: You turn a phone on and check it's battery after x amount of time without doing anything, and then repeat over the same amount of time doing the process in question and check the difference. Brute way of course :P

Comment: That is quite a broad question. In a nutshell you would write an implementation for each possible choice, in each you log battery levels over time and then compare the results to each other later. You would do it on a real device and try to limit other usage of the device while testing to limit outside influences.

Comment: So to summarise I have to log the battery levels while running the app. And then compare to when the WiFi is on always without the app running..

Answer (score 1):

The energy consumption should not be adversely affected by cycling every 10 minutes.  While it is true that state transitions incur higher power consumption, transitioning every 10 minutes will long overcome the penalty of the initial state transition.

I recently read a paper detailing this dilemma for the cellular antenna.  They concluded that as long as the cellular antenna was in a sleep state for longer than 9 seconds, the net energy consumption will be lower.  Although the cellular and wifi antennae are not strictly the same, I would expect the results to be similar.

Here is a cite for the paper:
Bo Zhao, Wenjie Hu, Qiang Zheng, and Guohong Cao. "Energy-Aware Web Browsing on Smartphones," IEEE Transactions on Parallel and Distributed Systems, 2014.